# How do I render time in twig without time zone interference

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I want to grab the time only from a Drupal Date Field, and render it in a twig template separately from its date.

In my twig template for Events I currently have date listed 3 ways:

```
{{ content }}
```

displays all the fields.
And the time (sourced from a Date field) displays correctly as;
28/04/2019 - 1:11
This is the correct time as per what was entered when the content was created.
On the same page, when using:

```
{{ content.field_date_start }}
```

28/04/2019 - 1:11
is also displayed corrected.
But I want to grab the time only to display separately from the date
so I put this in the twig:

```
{{ node.field_date_start.value|date("g:ia") }}
```

which displays as:
3:11am

This is incorrect, off by 14hours (the 1.11 when entered was 1.11 pm)

How do I separate the time to a separate display within twig, but also retain the correct time as per how it was entered.

How do I enter that into a twig?

I don't want the time to change if people are entering content or viewing content in different time zones.
Example - someone creates content in Melbourne, Australia and someone else views it in London, England - the time should display the same regardless.

Answer (score 3):

Drupal saves dates in the database as per the UTC timezone. E.g If you enter 09:00 AM as the time as a user who has a timezone of London (UTC + 1) selected in the profile, it is saved as 08:00 AM in the database. Same is true if the site's timezone is set to London (UTC +1).

I would suggest preprocessing the field and setting a variable for the start time.

```
function HOOK_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['elements']['#node'];
  $timezone = drupal_get_user_timezone();
  $formatter = \Drupal::service('date.formatter');
  $field_date_start = $node->get('field_date_start')->getValue()->getTimestamp();
  $time = $formatter->format($field_date_start, 'custom', 'g:ia', $timezone);
  $variables['start_time'] = $time;
}
```

And then print the value in the template as

```
{{ start_time }}
```

Comment: Hi Ajit S, I used your hook and twig code.  But no time displayed.
As a test I changed function HOOK_preprocess_node_event(&$variables)
to:
function HOOK_preprocess_node_events(&$variables)
(Because my Content Type is called "Events"). But this did not work either.
On each occasion I used "drush cr" in CLI and also Cleared Cache in Drupal / Performance to ensure pages were updating. But no date appeared.
I can also confirm my twig is styling the page as I have placed other test content in the twig which is displaying correctly.
Any idea what could be stopping this from working?

Comment: @AuxiliaryJoel Apologize for the mistyped function. It should be just `HOOK_preprocess_node(&$variables)`. Also, replace `HOOK` in the function name with your module or theme name where you are writing this function.